# zgrep -h doesn't work, zgrep --no-filename does?

Tags: ubuntu, grep, gzip

According to `man grep`:

```
-h, --no-filename
      Suppress the prefixing of file names on  output.   This  is  the
      default  when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
      search.
```

If I use `zgrep -h dhclient /var/log/syslog.*`, I still see the filenames. If I use `zgrep --no-filename ...`, it's all good.

What's going on?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Comment: It turns out that it works in 14.04 LTS; looking for changelogs...

Comment: Seems to be [bug 658734](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658734) also mentioned in the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gzip/gzip_1.6-4ubuntu1/changelog)

Answer (score 8):

The `zgrep` command is provided by the `gzip` package (according to `dpkg -S zgrep`); support for the `-h` switch was added in 2010-09-05, according to the gzip changelog (from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gzip/):

```
2010-09-15  Paul Eggert  <eggert@cs.ucla.edu>

   zgrep: fix parsing of -Eh options
   * zgrep.in: Update list of single-letter options to match what's
   in GNU grep.  Add -h as an alias for --no-filename.  Bug reported
   by Vladimir Sidorenko in
   <http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gzip/2010-09/msg00007.html>.
```

There's a related [change to the Ubuntu package](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gzip/gzip_1.6-4ubuntu1/changelog) and to the [upstream Debian package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658734). That changelog states that it's a "regression". It's not clear to me that this is actually the case, but the missing switch **works fine in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

*Hat tip to [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) for finding the Debian/Ubuntu changelogs.*